# image recognition with autofill in excel

Tags: excel, image-recognition, autofill

ok, so here is what I'm trying to do. I fill out a form (which is .xsl) but I want to build a macro that will open a  image recognition application and read a picture of a business card and paste the name in a cell in excel.. any info will be usefull..

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Neat business card scanner](https://www.neat.com/solutions/neat-solutions/business-card-scanning/) and export the data. Excel is the wrong tool for the job.